# How to chose the right LineByLineTextDataset-parameters for the transformers LineByLineTextDataset

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, roberta-language-model, huggingface

From [this website explaining the Roberta parameters](https://legacyai.github.io/tf-transformers/build/html/model_doc/roberta.html), I understood that the
`max_position_embeddings` should be a power of 2.
Then from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq/issues/1187), I understood that we should add 2 to the `max_position_embeddings` value while setting the `RobertaConfig` parameters.
So, we will get:

```
max_position_embeddings_value = 512 # power of 2
config = RobertaConfig(
    max_position_embeddings=max_position_embeddings_value+2
)
```

Now, I am wondering how to specify the `LineByLineTextDataset`-parameters.

```
from transformers import LineByLineTextDataset
dataset = LineByLineTextDataset(
                tokenizer=tokenizer,
                file_path='path_text.txt',
                block_size=max_position_embeddings_value,
            )
```

Do the `LineByLineTextDataset`-parameters depend on the `RobertaConfig`-parameters ?

1. Suppose each line in the `path_text.txt` file has a lenght of `n`.
   Should I specify the `max_position_embeddings`according to the lenght `n` ?
   e.g. what will be the value of `max_position_embeddings_value` if `n = 10`, or `n = 10` or `n = 500` or `n = 1000` ... `?
2. Should `block_size = max_position_embeddings_value` ? Does it depend on the lenght `n`?

I wanted to chose `max_position_embeddings_value` following this rule :

```
for n > 128 and n < 256, 
max_position_embeddings_value = 256, as it is a power of 2, closer to n and greater than n

for n > 256 and n < 512, 
max_position_embeddings_value = 512, as it is a power of 2, closer to n and greater than n

for n > 512 and n < 1024, 
max_position_embeddings_value = 1024, as it is a power of 2, closer to 10n24 and greater than n

etc ...
```

Is it a good approach ?